# Общий второстепенный член в ССП

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении "через три года она уехала(,) и на ее место был назначен А. В. Сидоренко" "через три года" является общим второстепенным членом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В некоторой степени от вас (автора) зависит, к чему отнести "три года": если вы хотите разорвать взаимосвязь событий "она уехала" и "(поэтому) на её место был назначен другой", то можно *не ставить* запятую - тогда "через три года" станет тем самым общим членом и два события будут трактоваться просто как произошедшие в одном и том же году (акцент на их привязке ко времени - в тот момент исчезла она и появился Сидоренко; оба вам одинаково безразличны, это фрагмент хронологии назначений и увольнений). Но (напр. в беллетристике или личном повествовании) видимая логика всего предложения - в зависимом положении второго события: скорее, "через три года" относится напрямую ко времени отъезда, а "назначение другого" объясняется фактом отъезда, причём "и" здесь имеет смысл "поэтому (нашли другого)"; возможно даже, Сидоренко и не сразу назначили, а, напр., полгода думали. Соответственно, больше оснований отнести проблемное "через три года" только к первой части предложения и *поставить* запятую.

Answer (score 5):

**Через три года** она уехала и на ее место был назначен А. В. Сидоренко.

Формально это общий второстепенный член, **нет паузы, нет запятой.**

Сравнить:  Через три года она уехала, и на ее место вскоре был назначен А. В. Сидоренко.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) Надо сказать, что авторские возможности в определении общего члена являются в какой-то мере **ограниченными той структурой ССП, которую автор выбирает**. Если это два нераспространенных предложения, то наличие запятой при общем члене могут посчитать за ошибку, например: **Всю ночь** шёл дождь и бушевал ветер.  **А кругом** солнце горит и земля цветёт. **Кое-где** виднелись небольшие леса и вились овраги. **Изредка** раздастся выстрел или ракета осветит местность.

2) **Для сравнения можно привести примеры**, в которых принято авторское решение об отнесенности "общего члена" к одному предложению (это обычно распространенные предложения, где явно описываются две ситуации и можно сделать паузу):    **Когда Каштанка проснулась**, было уже светло, и с улицы доносился шум, какой бывает только днём.   **Вечерами** обычно засиживались допоздна, и дружно и весело светились выходящие на улицу окна дома.

3) **Через три года** она уехала и на ее место был назначен А. В. Сидоренко.

Предложение **нераспространенное и похоже на простой перечень событий, случившихся "через три года"** (без отражения их взаимосвязи и возможной смещенности по времени). При желании передать подобную информацию предложение надо дополнить соответствующими структурными элементами (наречиями и т.д.).