# Общий член - запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Однако в нашу эпоху дискуссия актуализировалась, и мы все чаще сталкиваемся с тем, что религиозные деятели требуют изменения...

Можно ли считать слова "Однако в нашу эпоху" общим членом и тогда убрать запятую перед И?
*Сайт-источник не аргумент!*

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Общий второстепенный член в ССП](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427239/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b2-%d0%a1%d0%a1%d0%9f)

Comment: В "дубликате" очень полезное объяснение, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы не стал отказываться от запятой. И по формальным соображениям, и по стилистическим.
Да, обстоятельство времени можно считать общим членом, если автор настаивает. Но даже в этом случае запятая выглядит желательной по соображениям стилистики.

В отличие от случая общего члена в придаточных СПП, общий член в ССП не является императивным критерием, тут нужен еще анализ лексико-грамматических связей между простыми предложениями. Так, для отказа от запятой нужно, во-первых, очевидное отсутствие паузы (иначе запятая ставится по интонационным мотивам), и, во-вторых, еще какая-то внутренняя, стилистическая однородность предложений, а у нас два предложения разного грамматического вида (актуализировалась - совершенный вид; сталкиваемся - несовершенный), что препятствует такому пониманию. Тут скорее причинно-следственную связь можно усмотреть ("сталкиваемся" потому, что "актуализировалась"), в этом случае запятую опускать нельзя даже при наличии какого-то общего члена.

Впрочем, в конечном счете всё решается волей автора.

Comment: Классный ответ (объяснили бы так в школе!), спасибо! Запятую оставляю.